# How do akka nodes discover other nodes?

Tags: scala, akka

in akka cluster i would like to know a few more details about how the cluster works.
If i have a seed from A to B,C and from C to D and from D to E
then what if nodes D and E are restarted and D does not come up will E know the rest of the cluster? if not isn't that considered a problem?

Comment: How exactly do you have your cluster set up? You shouldn't be defining different seed nodes—they should all have the same configuration in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple seed nodes (A to E) and question is not aimed at cluster state management/convergence.

yes, seed node E will try to join the other seed nodes (A,B,C) even though node D is not up. As in the [Cluster Usage](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/cluster-usage.html) documentation

> Once more than two seed nodes have been started it is no problem to
>   shut down the first seed node. If the first seed node is restarted it
>   will first try join the other seed nodes in the existing cluster.

Comment: i still don't get it, how will E be aware of A,B,C after all it's not pointing to A,B,C as seeds but only to D

Comment: A Seed node means a regular node with a special role assigned as an initial contact point to the cluster. AFAIK there's no specific pointing mechanism in akka cluster. As per in the version 2.2 only the first seed node (which is the first in the list) has a restriction. That's the first node must be started when starting the cluster. Otherwise joining works like this, if a seed node (i.e E) needs to join the cluster it sends a joining ack to cluster and all running seed nodes will receive this and the node which replied first will be used as the initial contact point (can be A,B or C).

Comment: "it sends a joining ack to cluster" how is it aware of the rest of the nodes in the cluster?